# react-native-fcm ios not getting notification data in background

Tags: react-native, react-native-fcm

I'm sending notification from C# code

```
 {
        to: "fcm_token",
        notification: {
            body: "body test",
            title: "title test"
        }, 
       data:{
              body: "body test",
             title: "title test", 
             type="newentry"
        },
content_available:true
        }
```

I'm receiving notification on ios. I'm performing some actions in FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, notif => { method.

this.notificationListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {  method is only called when iOS app is in foreground not in background. When opening app clicked from notification this is never called.

Comment: iOS halts apps execution, so no code would run anymore until it's in the foreground again.

Comment: I need to navigate the user to some screen when notification is clicked. How can I do that then. Kindly suggest.

Comment: The functionality you are looking for is called deeplink. After clicking the banner and opening the app, use notifications data to navigate to your desired screen (depends on your navigator library).

Comment: Sorry to ask again but I'm using react-native-navigation and when app is in background and notification is clicked from banner no data for notification is received in notificationListener. I'm able to achieve this when app is in foreground as soon as notification is received user is navigated to the particular screen but can't do the same in background as no data is received and I cannot navigate the user.

Comment: You could use https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/deep-links but you need to send url parameter in notification. (not sure, never used fcm, I suggest onesignal)

Comment: Is there no way by which I can send some data-notification to the killed IOS app and then IOS will allow me to do some code execution in the background for some time?
I am using react-native-firebase and want to achieve this when IOS app is in killed state so that I can update the APP in background from the server